# Error: illegal Expression

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

I have this code:

```
tInteger :
   begin
       if(jinfo<maxinfo) then
        begin
          jinfo:=jinfo+1;
          lokasi[jinfo]:=ScanStr;
          WRITE(ResFile,jinfo:4);
        end;
        WRITE(ResFile,'   ');
        WRITE(ResFile,inum);
   end;`

   BEGIN
      ScanStr:='';
      REPEAT
           ScanStr:=ScanStr+cc;
           ReadChar;
      UNTIL NOT (cc in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z','0'..'9','_']);
      {Test KeyWord}
      TampStr:=UpperCase(ScanStr);
      i:=1; j:=JmlKeyWord; {index pencarian keyword dalam tabel}
      REPEAT
         k:=(i+j) DIV 2;
         IF TampStr<=KeyWord[k] THEN j:=k-1;
         IF TampStr>=KeyWord[k] THEN i:=k+1;
      UNTIL i>j;

      IF i-j>1 THEN
      BEGIN k:=k+ORD(tKurungTutup); Token := KeyToken; END
      ELSE
      BEGIN Token := tIdentifier;
      ScanStr:=COPY(ScanStr,1,10); END;
   end;
```

But the script gives me this error:

```
error:illegal expression
error:ordinal expression expected
fatal: Syntax Error,: Expected but identifier SCANSTR found
```

I don't understand this error message. I'm sure this script was right.

Comment: this character >>>> ` <<<< is part of your code? I think pascal doesn't has this sign.

Answer (score 2):

The "script" (which isn't a script - it's code) is wrong.

You're inside a `case` statement:

```
tInteger :
   begin
       if(jinfo<maxinfo) then
       begin
         jinfo:=jinfo+1;
         lokasi[jinfo]:=ScanStr;
         WRITE(ResFile,jinfo:4);
       end;
       WRITE(ResFile,'   ');
       WRITE(ResFile,inum);
   end;
```

The only thing valid after that is either another `case` branch, an optional `else` clause, or a final `end`.

```
case TheThing of
  ThingA:
    begin
      // Code here
    end;
  ThingB:
    begin
      // Code here
    end;
else
    // Else code here
end;
```

You have another full `begin..end` block, which is invalid syntax.

```
BEGIN
  ScanStr:='';
  REPEAT
       ScanStr:=ScanStr+cc;
       ReadChar;
  UNTIL NOT (cc in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z','0'..'9','_']);
  {Test KeyWord}
  TampStr:=UpperCase(ScanStr);
  i:=1; j:=JmlKeyWord; {index pencarian keyword dalam tabel}
  REPEAT
     k:=(i+j) DIV 2;
     IF TampStr<=KeyWord[k] THEN j:=k-1;
     IF TampStr>=KeyWord[k] THEN i:=k+1;
  UNTIL i>j;

  IF i-j>1 THEN
  BEGIN k:=k+ORD(tKurungTutup); Token := KeyToken; END
  ELSE
  BEGIN Token := tIdentifier;
  ScanStr:=COPY(ScanStr,1,10); END;
end;
```